# How to interface between SIM5360 and ATMEGA2560 by UART

Tags: arduino, circuit-design

Engineers.
Recently, I designed a device using SIM5360 and ATMEGA2560 based on the [3G_shield](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=SIM5360E_3G_Shield).

[image: SIM5360 circuit]

There is a circuit for the shift LEVEL because SIM5360 LEVEL is 1.8V.
I think the circuit is correct, but it doesn't work.
When ARMEGA2560 sends AT command to the SIM5360, SIM5360 doesn't respond.
To find the reason, I checked the voltage 2.8V of SIM5360 after POWLEY down-up(HIGH-LOW-HIGH). 2.8V is generated, but its waveform is uneven.
[image: 2.8V wave form from SIM5360]

But ATMEGA2560 sends AT command via the Tx of UART.
[image: Transfor AT command from ATMEGA2560]

Arduino code

```
#define FONA_RST 10
#define FONA_KEY 11


void setup() {
  // initialize both serial ports:
  Serial.begin(9600);///BLE
  Serial1.begin(9600);///TEST serial
  Serial2.begin(115200);///SIM5360
  Serial3.begin(9600);////CAN BUS

  pinMode(FONA_RST, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FONA_KEY, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(FONA_RST,HIGH);

  delay(20);

  digitalWrite(FONA_KEY,HIGH); 

  delay(200);
  Serial1.println("POWKEY lOW");
  digitalWrite(FONA_KEY,LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(FONA_KEY,HIGH);
  Serial1.println("POWKEY HIGH");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(FONA_RST,LOW);
  Serial1.println("RESTKEY lOW");
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(FONA_RST,HIGH);
  Serial1.println("RESTKEY HIGH");
  delay(500);

}

void loop() {

  if (Serial1.available()) { 
    Serial2.print((char)Serial1.read());
  }
  if (Serial2.available()) { 
    Serial1.println((char)Serial2.read());
  }
}
```

What's the reason that SIM5360 doesn't respond?
I'm waiting for the solution from someone.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, everybody.
The reason was Arduino Code
After check circuit(POWKEY, RESET)

```
pinMode(FONA_RST, OUTPUT);
pinMode(FONA_KEY, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(FONA_RST,LOW);
delay(20);
digitalWrite(FONA_KEY,LOW); 
delay(200);
Serial1.println("POWKEY lOW");
digitalWrite(FONA_KEY,HIGH);
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(FONA_KEY,LOW);
Serial1.println("POWKEY HIGH");
delay(1000);
```

Thank you for reading me.